# Hibernate mapping multiple class in one configuration file

Tags: hibernate, backend

I have 2 POJO's User and Gift and two tables user and gift. I want to mapping to both User and Gift classes(In database, user and Gift have no relation between them). I use annotation to define User and Gift classes. Below way is wrong, the reason is I only can add one , and the first mapping always works, but the second mapping throws exception.

```
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="hibernateSessionFactory">
  <mapping class="peppergo.GiftShop.Model.User"/> 
  <mapping class="peppergo.GiftShop.Model.Administrator"/>
 </session-factory>
```

How can I mapping two classes in one hibernate configuration file. 
I don't want to use Spring MVC this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can map any no. of classes or .hbm.xml file in hibernate configuration. There may be some problem with the second entity. Try commenting the first entity configuration and check.

Below is working for me:

```
   <mapping resource="resource/AccountTypeCodeMap.hbm.xml" />
   <mapping class="bo.Entity1"/>
   <mapping class="bo.Entity2"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have solved the problem by just adding:  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> in the web.xml